# MySQL: Subqueries for normalized databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, subquery, normalization

I've spent a lot of time on Google searching for this and also landed on Stackoverflow a few times, but I couldn't figure out how to fulfill my needs.

It might be pretty ease for most of you, but I just can't get it to work.

Let's assume I have this table:

**item_data**

[image]

And another one:

**vendor_data**

[image]

What I want to get is a query where I'm selecting one item from the first table, and the query should replace the vendor_id with the respective name specified in the second table - only for my output of course.

The logic is very easy, I think, but I just can't create a proper query.

Like:
I'm selecting the item with the id **2** from the table **item_data**, then I get the vendor_id that is also specified in **item_data**, this vendor_id is being looked up in **vendor_data** -> **vendor_id** (3) and the right **vendor_name** (CompanyZ) is brought back as my result.

I'd really appreciate your help, thanks!

- Andy

Comment: the nice thing about normalized tables is that you can "denormalize" in query results - a properly normalized structure where you select with multiple joins SHOULD produce a result identical to `select * from unnormalized_table`. so just slap some joins in there, e.g. `select ... from item_data left join vendor_data on ...` and you can get your vendor in the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are just wanting a simple join

```
SELECT i.item_id, i.item_name, v.vendor_id, v.vendor_name <-- select whatever fields you need here
FROM item_data AS i
INNER JOIN vendor_data AS v ON i.vendor_id = v.vendor.id
WHERE i.item_id = ?  <-- specify item_id for lookup here
```

Comment: Thanks! But which part returns the vendor_name back? (in my example CompanyZ)

Comment: @AndyTanner `v.vendor_name` would be the field that holds the data you want.  If that is the only field you want, than you can remove the others from the SELECT clause.

Comment: Oh, I just echo'ed the wrong row. Mike, I have to thank you very much, now I understand how it works!